# Anki не запускается. Anki requires Qt 5.9.0+

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решается проблема?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 6, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise Exception("Anki requires Qt 5.9.0+")
Exception: Anki requires Qt 5.9.0+
```

Comment: анки требует qt версии 5.9.0+. Чем мы можем вам помочь?

Comment: у меня имеется qt. и программа многократно запускалась исправно. Что сейчас пошло не так и как исправить?

Comment: вообще решается пересборкой (переконфигурированием) программы. но, учитывая, что код её (по крайней мере место возникновения ошибки) написано на интерпретируемом языке, возможно, достаточно подправить код, находящийся в файле /usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py где-то в районе 42-й строки.

Answer (score 1):

Если `pip3 show pyqt5` покажет Location: не в `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`

Пробуй

```
pip3 uninstall --user pyqt5
sudo pip3 uninstall pyqt5
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

Если там где надо, поставь все обновления

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Скорее всего работа компьютера бвла прервана при обновлении.